# php contact form after email sent not going to mailbox

Tags: javascript, php, html

here is my HTML code:

```
    <form class="contact_form contact_form_h" id="form" method="POST" name="contactform" 
            action="contact-form-handler.php"  style="margin-bottom: 10px;">

                <div>
                    <div class="input_holder">
                        <input class="field-name" type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name (required)">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input_holder">
                        <input class="email_field" type="text" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Address">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input_holder">
                        <input class="subject_field" type="text" id="company" name="company" placeholder="Company">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div>
                    <div class="input_holder">
                        <input class="field-name" type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Mobile">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input_holder">
                        <input class="email_field" type="text" id="calltime" name="calltime" placeholder="convenient time for ask to call you">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input_holder">
                        <input class="subject_field" type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="textarea_holder">
                    <textarea class="comment_field" id="message"  name="message" placeholder="Your query"></textarea>
                </div>

                <input type='submit' name='submit' value="submit">

            </form>
```

I have further attached the PHP code:

```
   <?php

             /* send the submitted data */

    $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
    $address=$_REQUEST['address'];
    $company=$_REQUEST['company'];
    $phone=$_REQUEST['phone'];
    $calltime=$_REQUEST['calltime'];
    $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
    $message=$_REQUEST['message'];
   if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message==""))
       {
        echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again.";
        }
    else{       
        $from="From: $name<$email>\r\n $subject \n $name \n $address \n $company \n $phone \n $calltime \r\n Return-path: $email";
        $subject="Message sent using your contact form";
        mail("email@website.com", $message, $from);
        echo "Email sent!";
        }

?>
```

I tried many searches and testing, but this is the most perfect code i was able to sort out. No idea why its not going to mail box, after submit button it still shows "Thank you" confirmation. Any resolution will be thankful.

Comment: have you looked in your apache error log? maybe your mail is not configured. or maybe wrong configured.

Comment: maybe its on the SMTP

Comment: check you $from the information u passing is not correct 
refer this link
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

Comment: place an if around the mail function and echo out your findings, this may help you track the issue down.

Comment: also this line here mail("email@website.com", $message, $from); this would be wrong, it should be mail($email, $message, $from);

Comment: @Shibon Can you please help me track down the error. Tried searching in the $from and the reference URL but seems i am still unable to track the accurate error.

Answer (score 0):

in else part change $from as header

```
$subject = "Your subject";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

 // More headers
 $headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";

 $message="From: $name<$email>\r\n $subject \n $name \n $address \n $company \n $phone \n $calltime \r\n Return-path: $email";

  mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: i think we will add $to separately right to receive emails ?

Comment: to is the person who need ot receive email

Answer (score 0):

I used this code:

```
 <form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">

<table width="450px">

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top"">

  <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="comments">Comments *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">   <a href="http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php">Email Form</a>

 </td>

</tr>

</table>

</form>
```

**And PHP form as:**

```
 <?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {


       $email_to = "you@yourdomain.com";

    $email_subject = "Your email subject line";





    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

        die();

    }



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {

        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

    }



    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required



    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>


Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.



<?php

}

?>
```

Now i need to just know how to redirect one to a definite page on successful submission.